# Does Delphi require dfm at compile time when dcu is present?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I always assumed that the dcu file is all that is needed at compile time. At least, the source files (pas and dfm) should not be required.

I have the following situation:

- A Delphi application with two units that each contain a form:

  - UMain contains form TMain
  - USubForm contains form TSubForm
- USubForm is in the uses clause of UMain
- After I compile this program, I removed USubForm.pas and USubForm.dfm and replaced them by the compiled USubForm.dcu.
- Compilation now results in an error:  `DCC : error : E1026 File not found: 'USubForm.dfm'`
- Note that if I only remove USubForm.pas (but leave USubForm.dfm file in place next to USubForm.dcu), the compilation works.

I don't understand. I thought the dcu file would be all I need (i.e. it's the compiled version of the pas + dfm file).

I'm using Delphi XE2 (we should be upgrading soon, but I don't think this is relevant for my question).

P.S. Some context: I'm trying to setup a continuous integration system for our in-house Delphi libraries and applications. I'd like to be able to compile applications without needing the source files of the libraries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you need the DFM file when you link your project. It's treated like a resource file. As I recall, it's *not* required when compiling.

Comment: I see, then I have been wrong all the time. It makes sense that it's treated like a resource file. And indeed, it's during linking, not compiling. Thanks.

Comment: A DCU is the compiled code for a PAS file only, it does not include the DFM.